# how to convert string into list using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

input:

```
id int not 
null,
firstname char not 
null,
```

output:

```
['id' 'int' 'not' 'null']
['firstname','char','not','null']
```

code:

```
with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        x = line.split()
```

something am missing in the code due to that am not getting proper output

Comment: I repaired the file lines of the input, but perhaps that is now not reflecting reality. Can you please review?

Comment: what do you want in it? your expected output format?

Comment: my input data itself single line is splitting into two lines (continuous line)

Comment: @reddy: that makes things even less clear, I'm afraid.

Comment: Try this:                                                                                                      with open("./abc.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        x = line.split(sep=" ")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
final_list = []
with open("wordchecking.txt", "r") as f:  # open your file
    for line in f:  # read it it line by line
        y = line.split()
        y = [z.replace(',','') for z in y]
        final_list.append(y)
for sub_list in final_list:
    print(sub_list)
```

Since you are using python 2:

```
print '[%s]' % ','.join(str(p) for p in sub_list)
```

output:

```
['id', 'int', 'not', 'null']
['firstname', 'char', 'not', 'null']
```

Comment: my input is spitted into two line i want in single line how can i achieve eg:['id','int','not' ] in one line and ['null'] is in another line if i capture first value in each line its throwing incorrect data. Please help me